# Why does TypeScript not validate the contents of an object returned from a function passed into props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a custom prop type that accepts either an object or a function that returns an object. When passing the function through a component's props, TS doesn't seem to verify the contents of the returned object.

```
export type RowPropsWithoutSx = Omit<TableRowProps, 'sx'>;

export type TableProps = {
  rowProps?: RowPropsWithoutSx | ((row?: TableData<T>) => RowPropsWithoutSx);
  // ... other props
}

export Table = (props: TableProps) => {
 // Table component code.
}
```

And then in another file, where I import the table component using the above prop types:

```
// In this example, TS correctly complains that sx does not exist in rowProps.
<Table 
  rowProps={{
    _focusWithin: undefined,
    sx: '',
  }}
/>

// In this example, TS does not complain that the returned object 
// does not match what's defined in rowProps.
<Table 
  rowProps={() => ({
    _focusWithin: undefined,
    sx: '',
  })}
/>
```

I understand that I have to define the function's return type to get TS to complain (`(): RowPropsWithoutSx => ({ ... }`), but I don't understand why TS won't recognize the incorrect return by default.

Answer (score 1):

This is another case of TypeScript [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) being operational only on a "fresh" object literal: (emphasis mine)

> when a **fresh** object literal is assigned to a variable or passed as an argument for a non-empty target type, it is an error for the object literal to specify properties that don’t exist in the target type.

You have a such *fresh* object literal when you use the direct object form of your prop, hence excess property check kicks in.

But when you use the functional form of your prop, you do not pass an object literal, but a function, which disables the feature.

And when you explicitly type the function return, if that function returns an object literal, it can be checked for excess properties within that function.

Comment: Is there a reason why TS can't just perform the same check on the function and its return without me explicitly declaring the return type? Seeing as how `rowProps` was also defined as `((row?: TableData<T>) => RowPropsWithoutSx)`.

Comment: As said above, this is no longer an object literal, but a function. Even though inside you have said object literal, TS excess property check is already disabled. And explicitly typing the return, just gives a chance for TS to check your actual return against that explicit type, which in this case can again trigger excess property check. But it no longer has anything to do with your prop: declaring your function standalone just does the same.